# Whole-Second Delays when communicating with AWS DynamoDB

Tags: php, curl, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am working to diagnose a strange symptom that I am seeing in my system's performance logs where occasionally, writes to DynamoDB are taking multiple seconds to complete.

To give some background on the infrastructure:

- This is a web application hosted in AWS (East region)
- An ELB covering two EC2 instances (c3.2xlarge)
- Single DynamoDB table provisioned for
  1000 reads/writes per sec

I have a PHP web service running on the EC2 instances that receives a small request from the connecting user, writes a record to dynamo, and returns an empty response.  The amount of data transferred is well under 1kb.  The traffic volumes to the ELB vary throughout the day, but range from a few requests per second to over 100.  An important note here is that I wrote a small CURL client directly for the dynamo operations I need since the AWS SDK was introducing a 70ms overhead on top of our processing times.

The only options I am using are:

```
CURLOPT_POST
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER
CURLOPT_TCP_NODELAY
```

On to the behavior I'm seeing:
For 99% of cases, the response times recorded by the ELB are under 30ms which is our target.  However if I change the graph to show maximums over the same range, I see a much different picture ([graph](http://i60.tinypic.com/2qrzzhe.png)), with times falling into near-whole second intervals.  This graph does not correlate with load, since it happens even in the middle of the night where traffic is minimal.  These trends prompted me to dig deeper and I was able to isolate the delay to the connection to DynamoDB.

These seem like programmatic thresholds, and not general noise.  My first thought was that it was exponential backoff, but I'm not seeing an indication in the responses from the dynamo web service that would suggest this (all 200's), and our throughput right now is 10% of our provisioning, even at peak.  And again, we see this performance trend even in the middle of the night when traffic is minimal.  If it's not backoff, then it definitely feels like some kind of throttling.  Ideas?

Using CURL's verbose output for my Dynamo API calls, I see entries like this:

```
Line 151190: 2014-03-12T16:48:35-04:00 - INFO - Time: 1.001436, (Start Transfer: 1.001416, DNS: 2.6E-5, Connect: 0.998141, Pre-Transfer: 0.998199)

Line 196871: 2014-03-12T16:48:42-04:00 - INFO - Time: 1.001528, (Start Transfer: 1.001488, DNS: 3.1E-5, Connect: 0.99694,  Pre-Transfer: 0.996981)

Line 430508: 2014-03-12T16:49:19-04:00 - INFO - Time: 1.002823, (Start Transfer: 1.002807, DNS: 3.2E-5, Connect: 0.998972, Pre-Transfer: 0.999009)

Line 870236: 2014-03-12T16:50:31-04:00 - INFO - Time: 1.000663, (Start Transfer: 1.000642, DNS: 3.0E-5, Connect: 0.001506, Pre-Transfer: 0.001537)

Line 950109: 2014-03-12T16:50:43-04:00 - INFO - Time: 1.010762, (Start Transfer: 1.010737, DNS: 3.3E-5, Connect: 0.001357, Pre-Transfer: 0.001394)
```

The key find here is it seems like in 50% of cases it's connection time, and for the other 50%, it's unclear where the time is being spent.  It seems like there's another component here that may be contributing to the end-to-end time, but I'm struggling to pinpoint what that might be.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What region is your Dynamo DB in?  Is it the same as your EC2 Instance?

Comment: Could it be DNS ? Are using an address or ip ? I have found using an ip can speed things up and not sure with the current AWS setup but could you use an internal address ?

Comment: @Ray - Yes, everything is in the same region

Comment: @OliverBS - We can certainly try that, but wouldn't that show up in the DNS time via CURL's logging?  Referring to the 5 samples in the original post, the DNS time seems negligible.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, this isn't really an area I am too savvy in. I just thought I would throw it out there :)

Comment: @user3412993 First, Can you make the curl request to dynamo on the command line of one of your EC2 instances behind the load balancer (not in php) and from your local computer, are there similar delays?  Second, are you EC2 instances in a VPC which the  Dynamo node is not part of?

Comment: @Ray I'm not familiar with how to check the dynamo node.  I do know that I only have on VPC configured in the region, but I don't see anywhere that indicates where the DynamoDB is connected.  I will amend the original post with the results of the local CURL test since the symptom is present there as well.

Comment: @Ray -- my apologies, I misinterpreted what you'd meant, and had to recreate the test.  I ran a trial of 1000 requests and found none that took over a second using straight-up curl against the dynamo API, so assuming it's an apples-to-apples comparison, this suggests to me that there's something in how myapplication/PHP is using CURL...

Answer (score 1):

Make you are not sending an `Expect: 100-continue` header, which is common cause for a ~1 second delay like this. I believe cURL sends this header by default, so you will need to do something to remove it.

If you end up using the AWS SDK for PHP, make sure you are also using an opcode cache like APC or Zend Opcache.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy -- I did come across this possibility as well while researching, and I've added code to ensure that I'm sending "Expect:" as the header, to override any default setting.  The strange thing I'm seeing though, I've turned on the CURLINFO_HEADER_OUTPUT flag, and I see neither my header, or Expect: 100-continue in it.  Could it be something that's hidden even one level further down?  All this is to say: I can't confirm that this has made an impact, but I do know that with adding and empty "Expect:" in my headers, I still see the 1 second delay.

Comment: when you do curl verbose output, you are not seeing `< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue` anywhere, right?

Comment: You should make sure to post on the DynamoDB forum as well: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=131

Comment: That's correct, I only see HTTP/1.1.  I did a little more digging on the DynamoDB forum and found others who experienced a consistent 1-second delay, referring to CURL's behavior of adding the header for larger payloads.  The size of the messages I'm sending over are around 160 bytes, and in my trials it is fairly sporadic despite all inbound traffic looking nearly identical (+/- 10 bytes).  I'll inquire on the AWS forum as well, and update here with any findings.  Thanks!